# Semaphore with Read/Write Lock

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

If a thread has lock on any object, can read methods still work ?

If I have object with various 'get' methods than can I use the object to do print outs while some other thread has lock on it ? I am working on project where object has various properties, which I need to print it out periodically. However, there are other threads running which may gain lock to write those properties. I am using Semaphore for synchronization. Also, I will be doing more reading than writing. What is the best approach to tackle these situation ?

Comment: ReentrantReadWriteLock might be more effective (Java 5+) http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html

Comment: @MarianP you should make this an answer

Comment: Locking an object does not prevent other threads from accessing it; it only prevents them from acquiring their own simultaneous locks on the object.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [***ReentrantReadWriteLock***](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) (Java 5+) is just made for your requirements.

Comment: Thanks Marian, these exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: well defined requirements produce easy answers.

Comment: semaphore is likely to be more effective and r/w lock, it has no ownership and doesn't require ThreadLocal per reader to keep the read count. A simple r/w lock is just semaphore w/ high permit count, reader take one permit, the write takes all. A main issue w/ r/w locks is that writer may get starved easily.